# Samba config GUI doesn't show after entering password

Tags: lubuntu, samba

To be able to share folder on lubuntu machine to be visible on from Windows 7, I had to share some folder with Samba.
Samba is installed and when:

1. [Start menu]
2. System Tools
3. Samba

Click on Samba, system asks for password, and nothing appears, no message, nothing.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Should run Samba from Terminal.

```
$ gksu system-config-samba
```

If returns error message with last line similar to this:

> SystemError: could not open configuration file '/etc/libuser.conf': No such file or directory

Create the missing file:

```
$ sudo touch /etc/libuser.conf
```

and run Samba again

```
$ gksu system-config-samba
```

Thanks Morbius1 for solution [ubuntuforum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2250379&p=13154944#post13154944).

Comment: `gksu` wasn't available on my **lubuntu** distro, although creating config with `sudo touch /etc/libuser.conf` and running `sudo system-config-samba` solved my issue