# Windows 7 Access Denied when Accessing Shared folder on Ubuntu Machine

Tags: networking, windows, files

Newbie to Linux and am trying to Share a folder on Ubuntu 16.04LTS with a Windows 7 Pro desktop.  The Windows Machine sees the Ubuntu machine when I go to Computer> Network, however when I click on the folder I receive the error message "Windows cannot access \HALCYONIDEAS\UNTITLEDFOLDER
You do not have permission to access \HALCYONIDEAS\Untitled Folder contact your network administrator to request access.

When trying to access a shared folder on the Windows Machine by going to Network in Cinnamon I get the message " Nemo cannot handle "network locations".

My sharing process is as follows used sudo apt-get install samba via terminal then right clicked on folder selected "Local network share" checked share this folder, allow others to create or delete and guest access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Install samba and its corresponding GUI tool (GUI will be much easier
  for first time users)

  `sudo apt-get  install  samba samba-common`

  `sudo apt-get install python-glade2`

  `sudo apt-get install system-config-samba`

  The last one is the GUI. If you get any missing dependencies, just do
  `sudo apt-get -f install` and all missing ones will be installed.
- Search samba in dash and open the Configuration tool (If nothing happens after entering the admin password when you launch samba, follow this answer 
  https://askubuntu.com/a/655183)
- Add a samba user from preferences and also look at the server settings in the preferences tab
- Add a samba share(the folder you want to share) using the "+ mark" and choose the settings you want. You have finally configured your Linux part of the share
- Go to the windows machine and go to NETWORK in Windows Explorer. You will find your linux machine there. Double Click to connect and enter the username and password that **you have decided while adding the samba user**
- You can see all the shared folders of that Linux Machine there and can browse the files.

For more you may refer these links for screenshots:

https://www.unixmen.com/howto-install-and-configure-samba-share-in-ubuntu/

https://superuser.com/questions/347492/how-to-connect-to-an-smb-share

Comment: I double click on samba it asks for my admin password then nothing happens :(.

Comment: @iceblade2097 yes this happens. Here's your fix https://askubuntu.com/a/655183 i assume double click in the sense you search in the dash, then click on 'samba'?

Comment: Yay! that worked thanks a lot! :)  One more question though.  Does Ubuntu desktop enviroment have a gui interface to see computers on the network?  Cinnamon had something similar to windows where you go to computer and under the subsection "network" it would lists all the computers on the network.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/512749/574724. This answer gives you the GUI tool for seeing computers on your network(also check out the other command line tools on the same question page). And don't forget to mark my answer as accepted if your windows part is working right, since that's what you expected of your question...   @iceblade2097